# How to load encoded image from file into html

Tags: html, image, encoding

I can include an encoded image in HTML using:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo......" />
```

Is there a way I could have the encoded data in a separate file? I tried the obvious of

```
<img src="encoded-image.txt" />
```

I can do it using javascript.

```
$.get( "encoded-image.txt", function( data ) {
  $("#load-me").attr('src', data);
});
```

Is there a direct way?

Example here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/HfS7IUCMhVDlF2UI6hVN?p=preview

Comment: If you're trying to embed a base64-encoded PNG as an `<img>` without JavaScript, why not just embed the PNG file itself? What's the goal here?

Comment: To add to my question above, I want to note that the PNG in your example is 15KB, but when base64-encoded, it becomes 20KB (33% larger).

Comment: @JonUleis it's just because encoded images create insanely long strings that mess up nice html code. The image in the example is NOT the sort of image I'm wanting to use in practice. I'm talking big images.

Comment: I understand that, but it doesn't answer my question. Why base64-encoded images instead of PNG files?

Comment: @JonUleis OH!!! I see. Well...not sure I can think of a completely practical application. I'm doing some testing in Plunker, and wanted to include an image without linking to something that might go away.

Comment: Ha, gotcha. imgur.com is a good, free permanent image host, fyi.

Comment: Good point. For some reason, those kinds of services just seem a bit sketchy to me. But I know they are used ALL the time on here.